# Angular 1.6 with web-pack and es6 module compiled successfully but not running in browser

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

I am trying to develop angular 1.6 with es6 . syntax and using web pack and yarn with help of this [article](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/) and when execute `yarn run start` , webpack compiled successfully but when open `localhost:8080/` in the browser it says *can not get /*

here is the relevant code

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

const config = {
  context : __dirname,
  entry: APP_DIR + '/app/app.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR ,
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devtool : 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        contentBase: "./public"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: { presets: ['env'] }
      },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html" },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.inline.svg$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader!svg-react-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|^(?!.*\.inline\.svg$).*\.svg$/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      },
      {
          test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf)$/i,
          loader: 'url-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.html', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.less']
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "es6angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Es6 System",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.7",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.7",
    "angular-aria": "^1.6.7",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^0.12.2",
    "angular-chart.js": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-messages": "^1.6.7",
    "angular-resource": "^1.6.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.6.7",
    "angular-toastr": "^2.1.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.4.3",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "^0.18.0",
    "angular-ui-validate": "^1.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "fontawesome": "^4.7.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "international-phone-number": "^0.0.11",
    "intl-tel-input": "^12.1.6",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.4",
    "ng-table": "^3.0.1",
    "ngstorage": "^0.3.11",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-env": "^2.4.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^4.13.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

#### app/app.js

```
'use strict';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import ngMessages from 'angular-messages';
import uiBootstrap from 'angular-bootstrap';

import routing from './app.config';
import home from './home';

angular
 .module('app', [ngMessages, uiRouter, uiBootstrap, home])
 .config(routing);
```

#### app/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular ES6</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Application Manager">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  </head>
  <body class="top-navigation" >
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### app/app.config.js

```
routing.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];

export default function routing($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

#### home/home.controller.js

```
export default class HomeController {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'World';
  }

  changeName() {
    this.name = 'angular-tips';
  }
}
```

#### home/home.route.js

```
routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

export default function routes($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateURL: './home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController',
      controllerAs: 'home'
    });
}
```

#### home/home.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Hello, {{home.name}}</h1>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="home.changeName()">Change</button>
```

#### home/index.js

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uirouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import routing from './home.route';
import HomeController from './home.controller';

export default angular.module('app.home', [uirouter])
  .config(routing)
  .controller('HomeController', HomeController).name;
```

other files can be found here in this [URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-svrw4x?file=index.html), although this file is not running but only contains the code

What is wrong in this?

below is `yarn run start` log in terminal

```
    warning package.json: No license field
    $ webpack-dev-server --hot
    Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
    webpack output is served from /
    Content not from webpack is served from ./public
    404s will fallback to /index.html
    Hash: b429c9fda4e99e95ee12
    Version: webpack 3.10.0
    Time: 2243ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    bundle.js  6.16 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
       [0] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
       [4] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
       [7] ./node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js 175 kB {0} [built]
       [8] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/app/app.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
       [9] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.95 kB {0} [built]
      [10] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
      [17] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
      [19] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.86 kB {0} [built]
      [20] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 kB {0} [built]
      [22] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.73 kB {0} [built]
      [29] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 kB {0} [built]
      [31] ./src/app/app.js 921 bytes {0} [built]
      [41] ./node_modules/angular-messages/index.js 62 bytes {0} [built]
      [43] ./node_modules/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js 143 kB {0} [built]
      [45] ./src/app/home/index.js 657 bytes {0} [built]
        + 33 hidden modules
    webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Please post the complete logs which you receive after running the `yarn run start` command.

Comment: added in the question. please check

Comment: I thought another server might be running on the same port, but the logs don't tell so.

Comment: no. nothing is working in the same port. i have checked with `ps`

Comment: Can you check using the browser's developer tools that the contents of `index.html` are being received on the browser?

Comment: no content is being recieved. only error html '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>
'  one strange thing is that favicon showing the react icon

Comment: contentBase: "./public" -- This one is incorrect for sure. Actually this should be folder where index.html is located. Try '.' or 'src' and see what happens.

Comment: I have changed as per your suggestions. my current setting is as below `output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/',
    devtoolLineToLine: true,
    pathinfo: true
  },
  devtool : 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
        publicPath: '/',
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname , "/src/app"),
        compress: true,
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
  },`

Comment: BUT now it's giving another error `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {} due to: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function,`